# Change Detection not firing Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection, angular-ivy

I have just updated my application to angular 9

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.3
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.3
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router, service-worker
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.3
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.3
@schematics/angular               9.1.3
@schematics/update                0.901.3
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.7.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

now basically my app was working fine before the update, and now after the update the regular change detection strategy doesnt seem to be firing.

For example I have a component like so

**component.ts**

```
// ...

@Component({
    selector: 'app-library',
    templateUrl: './library.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./library.component.scss'],
})

// ...


constructor(
  private bookService: BookService
) {}

books: Book[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.getBooks();
}

getBooks() {
  this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe(result => {
    this.books = result;
  })
}
```

**component.html**

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let book of books">{{book.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

now when I `console.log` the result from `getBooks` I can see that 100 books get returned, but its not updating the view the screen remains empty..

Now I know I can do this

```
constructor(
   private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

// ...

getBooks() {
  // ...
  this._cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

but this seems inefficient, and now I will have to go through my entire application and put it anywhere a value is updated...

I can't find any references online about change detection differences between 
8 -> 9... does anyone know what is going on here??

**EDIT**

Just to clarify calling `this._cdr.detectChanges()` fixes the problem and the DOM updates

**EDIT 2**

It only seems to be an issue on the initial page load, after that if you change the state the page updates.. weird

Comment: Is `this.books.getBooks()` a typo - should it be the name of a service? Can you recreate the problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: @KurtHamilton no everything was working fine before the update - and now after it doesnt seem to be firing the normal change detection - as I wrote in the post this has happened to all of my service calls - and anytime state is updated

Comment: What I mean is, you are calling `getBooks()` on a type that is declared as `Book[]`. I'm not saying it's a cause of the problem, just that it looks like a typo. And can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Comment: Assuming it is a typo I see no reason why change detection won't fire. Need a reproducer to look further into it.

Comment: No typos, as I said before nothing has changed other than what was ran by angular - seems weird

Comment: I will try to re-create the issue - I assumed that maybe there was some breaking change I was unaware of

Comment: @KurtHamilton I can see the confusion, I called the service books as well as the variable, I have updated the question - this isnt my actual code just dummy code for explanation

Comment: Again, no reason why angular wouldn't do change detection as you re-assign a template bound variable. You should change `books: Book[];` to `books: Book[] = []` though.

Comment: @SmokeyDawson Perhaps there is a parent component with a `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. If that's the case, every child will inherit this strategy. Also, it's anyways best to use this strategy, because it drastically improves performance. Instead of `subscribe` you should actually just use the `Observable` straight in your template using the `async` pipe. I know this doesn't answer your question, so just giving it as a comment :)

Comment: @PoulKruijt That's interesting, is the difference really that 'drastic'? Afaik, angular does change detection very quickly, unless the application has a really large component structure. Also why is `| async` better than assigning the observable result to a component variable?

Comment: @MikeS. A large component structure is not the only reason. Just imagine you are getting data from an API with +100 items. And you use an `*ngFor` to display this. Every cycle it needs to go over these items to see if something has changed. Another great benefit is that you -know- when change detection is ran in a component. Either when an input changes or when an event is fired within the component. This makes the code more readable and less prone to unwanted behavior. About the async, this is better because you don't have to handle the subscription and the change detection. It's magic :)

Comment: @PoulKruijt yes you are right, the parent element had onPush change detection! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if book object have id field you can override change detection with trackBy function

```
// ts
trackBy: (book) => book.id

// html
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let book of books; trackBy: trackById">{{book.title}}</li>
</ul>
```